# select image as blob from mysql and delete from disk after show in page

Tags: javascript, php

as the title suggests, I need to view images and then erase them from the disk.
I can export them from the db and have them displayed correctly, but then I stop: either I visualize them or I delete them. I can't do both.

at the end of page, Afer the php code i try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {

if (event.target.readyState === "interactive") {   
    setTimeout(function(){
        <?php
        $tags = explode('|',$del);
        foreach($tags as $key) {    
            exec ('rm -f '.$path.$key.'.gif');    
        }
        ?>

    }, 7000);
}

});
</script>
```

in this javascript if i insert a message it displays it (e.g. hello world) after the full load of the page and after the interval. If I enter the php code it executes it immediately. Why?

Comment: I don't get your question. Where does it select anything from a database? And please look up the difference between server-side programming (in PHP) and client-side (in JS)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: In regards to *If I enter the php code it executes it immediately* ... is the nature of PHP rendering. It will execute before the DOM is fully loaded. So the difference would be a js event which does dynamic type things, for the PHP to also be dynamic, you'd need an AJAX call in your event handler to another (or same) PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about ajax :\ 
so, how could I modify the script to make those few instructions in php execute after the page has been completely loaded?